# How to take aggregations for a repeating window in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset where there is an `id` which has steps. Each step has a timestamp and the channel name. A channel can repeat several times at multiple timestamps for a given id.

I am trying to measure for each chunk of the repeating channels (ordered by the timestamp), how many occurrences happen?

Here is my sample data -

```
with temp as (
select 1 as id, '2019-08-02 13:13:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel union all
select 1 as id, '2019-08-02 13:14:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel union all
select 1 as id, '2019-08-02 13:15:27 UTC' as t_date, 'display' as channel union all
select 1 as id, '2019-08-02 13:16:27 UTC' as t_date, 'display' as channel union all
select 1 as id, '2019-08-02 13:17:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel union all
select 1 as id, '2019-08-02 13:18:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel union all
select 2 as id, '2019-08-02 13:11:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel union all
select 2 as id, '2019-08-02 13:12:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel union all
select 2 as id, '2019-08-02 13:13:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel union all
select 2 as id, '2019-08-02 13:14:27 UTC' as t_date, 'email' as channel 
)

select id, channel , count(1) appearances
from temp
group by id , channel
order by id
```

which gives me output as
[image]

However, I need something like this -
[image]

As shown in the output, for each sequences of the channels occurring together, I need to count the `appearances` and the start and end times. For instance, the first record in the output belongs to `email` channel that started for id = 1 at `2019-08-02 13:13:27 UTC` and ended at `2019-08-02 13:14:27 UTC` - ordered by timestamp. The last column shows many how many times `email` channel repeats before it changes to next one (display in this case).

How can I achieve this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, channel, 
  min(t_date) as start_date, 
  max(t_date) as end_date, 
  count(1) as appearances
from (
  select *, countif(new_group) over (partition by id order by t_date) group_id 
  from (
    select *, ifnull(channel != lag(channel) over win, true) new_group
    from temp
    window win as (partition by id order by t_date)
  )
)
group by id, channel, group_id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I think only change I need is `max(t_date) as end_date` to get the correct end date. Can you please explain why you have used the partition by id twice in your windowing functions?

Comment: sure. of course max for end_date :o) i corrected my answer